# How to make a ground object follow a flying object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an object on the ground follow a flying object, for example a drone leading a human (for now i'm just using shapes - a cube and a capsule). My cube follows the capsule like i desire but i  want the cube to follow the capsule on the ground only, rather than go up on the y-axis with the capsule. Right now, it follows the capsule everywhere, I want the capsule to lead while the cube follows along on the ground.

I have done some research on Google and Youtube but I have not seen any results. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

This is the code script attached to the cube(ground object)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class follow_target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform mTarget;
    float mSpeed = 10.0f;
    const float EPSILON = 0.1f;

    Vector3 mLookDirection;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       mLookDirection = (mTarget.position - transform.position).normalized;
       if((transform.position - mTarget.position).magnitude > EPSILON)
          transform.Translate(mLookDirection * Time.deltaTime * mSpeed); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a trig problem.   You have a right triangle with the human at one vertex and the drone at the second vertex and the right angle a the location on the ground where drone is located.  So the ground location is x = drone X, y = drone Y, z = 0.  Just set the z location to zero.

Comment: @jdweng why `Z` ? In Unity `Z` is forward, `Y` is up ...

Comment: Because of my Linear Algebra and Mechanics Courses in college.  What direction is "X"?  You have a 3-D world that Unity is trying to display on a 2-D screen.

Answer (score 1):

If the ground is planar, you can just set the y component to 0 (or whatever the ground y vector is).

If the ground changes in topology, you can do a raycast down from the capsule to get the hit point (vector3).  You can use the hit point y component for the height.  After that you will need to set the cubes rotation so that it is aligned to the ground.  You could do that with a raycast as well, there are a number of examples of that online.

I hope that helps get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a flat ground on `Y = 0`

either make sure your objects sticks to the ground so set

```
private const float EPSILONSQR = EPSILON * EPSILON;

void Update()
{
    var difference = mTarget.position - transform.position;
    mLookDirection = difference.normalized;
    if(difference.sqrmagnitude > EPSILONSQR)
    {
        // In general be aware that Translate by default moves in the
        // objects own local space coordinates so you probably would rather
        // want to use Space.World
        transform.Translate(mLookDirection * Time.deltaTime * mSpeed, Space.World); 

        var pos = transform.position;
        // reset the Y back to the ground
        pos.y = 0; 
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

or simply already map the direction down on the XZ plane (ignoring any difference in Y) like

```
private const float EPSILONSQR = EPSILON * EPSILON;

void Update()
{
    var difference = mTarget.position - transform.position;
    mLookDirection = difference.normalized;
    // simply ignore the difference in Y
    // up to you if you want to normalize the vector before or after doing that
    mLookDirection.y = 0;

    if(difference.sqrmagnitude > EPSILONSQR)
    {
        transform.Translate(mLookDirection * Time.deltaTime * mSpeed, Space.World);
    }
}
```